# C++ while(getline()) not working properly

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I am using getline to start reading in info from a file. The problem is that it will never enter the while loop, even though there is data in the file to read. Does anyone see what the issue might be? I know my code may not be the best formatted, but right now I am strictly concerned with the while(getline())

```
void loadPatients(Doctor Doctor[], int size)
{
    std::ifstream patientFile;
    Patient** patientInfo;
    std::string Address, DoctorId, Id, Name, PhoneNumber,junk;
    int patientNumber;
    patientInfo = new Patient*[size];
    for (int b = 0; b < size; b++)
        patientInfo[b] = new Patient[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        DoctorId = Doctor[i].getId();
        patientFile.open(DoctorId);
        patientNumber = Doctor[i].getNumberOfPatient();
        for (int a = 0; a < patientNumber; a++)
        {
            while (getline(patientFile, Name))
            {
                getline(patientFile, Id);
                getline(patientFile, Address);
                getline(patientFile, PhoneNumber);
                getline(patientFile, DoctorId);
            }
            patientInfo[i][a].setAddress(Address);
            std::cout << Address;
            patientInfo[i][a].setName(Name);
            patientInfo[i][a].setDoctorId(DoctorId);
            patientInfo[i][a].setId(Id);
            patientInfo[i][a].setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber);
        }
        patientFile.close();

    }
```

Comment: If it never reaches the while loop, then check the for loop termination conditions, so check size and patientNumber.... Use cout statements and see where it doesn't enter

Comment: I have already done that, I should have probably mentioned that, it gets to the line before the while loop, but does not enter it

Comment: Can you try while(patientFile.good()) , and move the getline(patientFile,Name) inside the while and see if it goes inside the loop

Comment: ah ok so it still didn't go in, so something is wrong with opening the file then

Comment: Yes so check what DoctorId is.

Comment: ok I got it, the doctor id that is being used to open the file does not have the .txt extension, so it couldn't open. Thanks for pointing the .good() out to me!

Comment: No problem, best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

patientFile.open(DoctorId) needs the .txt extension to it.. so patientFile.open(DoctorId+".txt")